# Sub GHZ Audio transmission with radiohead library

Tags: uhf

Can I use sub-ghz (433 Mhz) to transmit audio.I already used radiohead library with RFM96 to transmit small packets of data and built a point to point mesh chat application.
Now i wanted to test FSK supported chip like rfm69hcw to transmit audio in 433Mhz ISM band. i think audio needs a data rate of 5-6 kbps. RFM69hcw supportsit. My question:

1. Will it work for HALF-duplex quality audio transmission?
2. Can this be done with rfm69 and radiohead library, as radiohead has a packet length limitation

Thanks

Comment: Watch out for the 10% duty cycle and bandwidth limitations in the 433 ISM band, and the rule of "no audio and voice". See also [this question](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/7105/can-433-mhz-amateur-bands-be-used-for-ism-purposes)

Comment: Thanks @tomnexus. We are working for goverment in south-east asia. Permission is not an issue.Also this is for test purpose. What i wanted to know if anyone has done this? Also radiohead library and with rfm69 is this achievable?

Comment: Hello and welcome to ham.stackexchange.com!